# How do I soften home made Split Pea with crunchy Peas?

Tags: legumes

I got some Split Pea Soup from my Fiance's Nannie, who got it from a friend.  The soup tasted ok, but it  was like really chunky like the spoon stood up on it's own.  So I added water and reheated it.  The water didn't help the Peas were *Still Crunchy* Please Help What do I do?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Does [this answer your question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/73185/split-pea-soup-wont-soften-any-way-to-soften-the-peas-without-burning)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split pea soup won't soften. Any way to soften the peas without burning?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/73185/split-pea-soup-wont-soften-any-way-to-soften-the-peas-without-burning)

Answer (score 1):

### ...cook it more.

Really all there is to it - if the peas are not sufficiently cooked, they need more cooking. So re-heat and keep it re-heated (simmering) for as much as several hours, until the peas are no longer crunchy.